# Open new tab with current directory in WSL2 by ConEmu

Tags: bash, conemu, wsl2

I'm using WSL2 with ComEmu.
When I just setup a task only by `wsl.exe` it open the bash with `/mnt/c/Users/username` directory. So I set up the command like this.

```
wsl.exe -cur_console:pm:/mnt ~
```

With this config I can open a bash terminal with home directory in Ubuntu.

After that I created a `my_project` directory and change current to it.

```
mkdir my_project
cd my_project
```

Now I open a new tab, then I go back to my Ubuntu home directory.
How can I open a new bash tab while keeping current directory?

### Reply to the comments

I open a new tab by a keyboard shortcut that triggers `Create new {Ubuntu} console` command or just click the `+` icon. I configured `Ubuntu` task as default.

Comment: How do you open new tab?

Comment: I spent a bit looking into this.  What I think you are asking for is for your first tab to open to `~`, but then subsequent tabs/sessions to use the current directory of the current tab?  I looked at the ConEmu docs for a bit, and I didn't see any obvious way to do this.  The docs even say that it is challenging to get the current directory from a WSL session.  You have to hook your PS1 (prompt) to send a message back up to ConEmu.  Then you are still left with the "conditional" of determining if you are opening the first tab or a subsequent one, and I didn't see a way to do that.

Comment: @Maximus I added info to my question.

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted. If I add another condition, when I use different shell in current tab, I want to open Ubuntu home dir. So it seems quite difficult now, I gonna use `cd` command after I open a new session. Thanks.